# xymatrix arrow changing directions

Tags: arrows, xy-pic, xymatrix

In an `\xymatrix` environment, how can I get an arrow going down, then two steps right and then up again, as in the picture?
[image]

In the good old days there was LAMSTeX to do this kind of things, but not anymore.
From the XYPic manual I realize that I have to use the grave accent to type directions but I couldn't figure out how, and furthermore arrows displayed in that manual are bending and not changing direction at straight angles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a direct answer to your question, but `tikz-cd` is *much* better than Xy-pic.

With some help from the manuals and a bit of luck…

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,tikz-cd,eucal}

\DeclareMathOperator{\ind}{ind}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=large]
V_m \arrow[r,"\iota"]
  \arrow[rr,"{\phi_{m+b,m}}",
    to path = { -- ++(0,-2em) -| (\tikztotarget)[near start]\tikztonodes },
  ]
&
\ind_{\mathcal{S}_m\times\mathcal{S}_b}^{\mathcal{S}_{m+b}}(V_m\boxtimes\mathcal{A}_b)
  \arrow[r,"{\Phi_{m+b,m}}"] &
V_{m+b}
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with bending angles:

```
\ar `d[d] `[rr]^-{\phi_{m+b,m}}  [rr]
```

Could someone please explain how it works?

Why is there a `d` outside the brackets and then one inside the brackets?

Why is there no `r` outside the brackets for the second segment?

How does xy know at what angle to finish the arrow if there is no third segment?

Is there a solution with sharp angles?

Answer (score 0):

Surely there is a lot of work to build with `xy` package your image...In fact I have used near one hour :-(...I'm not as the light ....and I think that `xy` package not have the square but curved arrow that connect two elements of a matrix.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,eucal}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\begin{document}
$\xymatrix@C=4pc{%
        V_m \vphantom{\scaleobj{2.5}{\frac AB}}\ar[r]^{\mkern-80mu\iota}  \ar@<-1pt> `d/5pt[r] `[rr]^{\phi_{m+b,m}} [rr]  &
        \text{Ind}^{\mathcal{S}_{m+b}}_{\mathcal{S}_{m}\times \mathcal{S}_{b}}(V_m \boxtimes \mathcal{A}_b)  \ar[r]^{\mkern50mu\mathit{\Phi}_{m+b,m}}
        &
        V_{m+b}
    }$
\end{document}
```

[image]